# how Jquery UI Datepicker value set when redirect to this page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

When i submitted form than if error occurred than value is not set in datepicker which is selected before. Datepicker field empty . how this possible ??

```
 <html>       
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" >.
             $(function() {
                    $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: '1900:'
                });
                $( "#dob" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );
            });
        </script>
</head>
<body> 
   <form>
        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['dob'])) echo $_SESSION['dob']; ?>" placeholder="Please enter date of birth" required/>
   </form>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.. can you please explain it...

Comment: You mean setting the selected value in datepicker if the page reloads on error?

Comment: yes #K K... i exactly this mean.

Comment: sorry id="dob". when i change this id then value is selected but datepicker not working.

Comment: but when id="dob" then value is not selected

Comment: Maybe because you don't have anything in $_SESSION['dob']. Try logging it

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this issue.

1. Either the dob variable is null/empty/undefined.
2. The dob value is not in the correct format.
3. You have not used `defaultDate` in the datepicker.

For 1st part, you can only log and debug what is wrong.

For 2nd part, you can format the value in correct format. Search on SO for formatting a string to Date.

For the 3rd part:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dob").datepicker({
        defaultDate: $(this).val(), //Add this
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', // And this too
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:'
    });
});
```